# Getting black screen in 13.10

Tags: nvidia

i recently install Nvidia  drivers through terminal using the command "sudo apt-get install Nvidia-323.86 after complete installation i upgrade packages using upgrade command.
after that i shutdown it. later after enter password only black screen shown. by enter terminal shortcut key i can open my terminal.. from terminal i also open some software's like vlc. i tried my things like rm some config file and auto remove and and install upgrade and update install nvidia. remove -- purgge nvidia.*.  but  did't solve this problem.. plz give me perfect solution..  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try removing bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bumblebee
```

If that doesnt work then try including nomodeset as a boot option in grub. From the main grub bootloader press 'e' to edit the boot parameters. Find where it reads:

```
quiet splash
```

Edit to look like this:

```
quiet splash nomodeset
```

Hopefully this will solve your boot issue.

Comment: Try rolling back to a different nvidia driver. 319-updates is the latest supported on 13.10.